# SQL Server : querying XML from column. Getting duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am working on learning how to query for data from a column where XML files are stored.

The XML files contain some information as comment as I am trying to fetch since the comment isn't in the file in all cases. It all depends on the response code in the XML file.

I am at a point where I am starting to confuse myself from trying different ways.

The files can have 1 or more (5, 10, 100, 1000 etc) `PaymentStatus` nodes.

I need to fetch the following from the files:

1. ReasonCode/Code
2. ReasonInformation
3. Comments in the file

I am having 2 issues:

**Problem #1**

- Some files contain information (`ReasonInformation` (in a node which I do not need)). This information is of no use. This value will be different between files, so I can't use a case/IIF to skip it
- I need the value from the `ReasonCode` and `ReasonInformation` node below.
- I need to skip the first one always, but fetch all the `ReasonCode` and `ReasonInformation` below.

[image: XmlProblem1]

**Problem #2**

- Comment is duplicated to the all the `ReasonCode` and `ReasonInformation` in the node.
- I'd like it to only exist for the `ReasonCode` and `ReasonInformation` node it belongs to.

[image: XmlProblem2]

[image: XmlProblemResult2]

The result I am looking for:

| Code | ReasonInformation | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 011 | Creditor account info invalid or missing | This is a comment |
| 012 | Creditor payment info invalid or missing |  |
| 001 |  |  |
| 034 | Invoice number is mandatory | Invoice number is invalid or missing |

**SQL fiddle**, XML files and SQLs for creating the table

Adding SQL fiddle as well as the XML files and SQLs to create the SQL fiddle if it were to not work, or if it stops working at a later time in case others are struggling with the same problem.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c42a24/3

**XML files**

XML file with `ID = 1`

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:abc:Example">
<CInfo>
        <Id>12345678</Id>
        <Created>2023-07-12</Created>
        <Customer>
            <Id>
                <Org>Demo Org</Org>
                <Id>88343434</Id>
            </Id>
        </Customer>
    </CInfo>
    <PaymentStatus>
        <OrgPaymentFileID>1234567</OrgPaymentFileID>
        <PaymentStatusInfo>
            <PaymentId>422049343</PaymentId>
            <Status>Rejected</Status>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>011</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
                <!-- This is a comment -->
                <ReasonInfo>Creditor account info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>012</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
                <ReasonInfo>Creditor payment info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
        </PaymentStatusInfo>
        <PaymentStatusInfo>
            <PaymentId>24234234</PaymentId>
            <Status>Rejected</Status>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>011</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
                <ReasonInfo>Creditor account info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>012</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
                <ReasonInfo>Creditor payment info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
        </PaymentStatusInfo>
        <PaymentStatusInfo>
            <PaymentId>8453453</PaymentId>
            <Status>Accepted</Status>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>001</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
            </StatusInfo>
        </PaymentStatusInfo>
    </PaymentStatus>
</Document>
```

XML file with `ID = 2`:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:abc:Example">
<CInfo>
        <Id>3852323</Id>
        <Created>2023-07-12</Created>
        <Customer>
            <Id>
                <Org>Demo Org</Org>
                <Id>88343434</Id>
            </Id>
        </Customer>
    </CInfo>
    <PaymentStatus>
        <OrgPaymentFileID>349232</OrgPaymentFileID>
        <PaymentStatusInfo>
            <PaymentId>193483</PaymentId>
            <Status>Rejected</Status>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonInfo>123345345</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>034</Code>
                    <!-- Invoice number is invalid or missing -->
                </ReasonCode>
                <ReasonInfo>Invoice number is mandatory</ReasonInfo>
            </StatusInfo>
        </PaymentStatusInfo>
        <PaymentStatusInfo>
            <PaymentId>4083421</PaymentId>
            <Status>Accepted</Status>
            <StatusInfo>
                <ReasonCode>
                    <Code>001</Code>
                </ReasonCode>
            </StatusInfo>
        </PaymentStatusInfo>
    </PaymentStatus>
</Document>
```

SQL queries for SQL fiddle

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyXmlTable
(
    ID Int,
    XmlData varchar(max)
)
  
INSERT INTO MyXmlTable 
VALUES (1,
   '<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:abc:Example"> <CInfo>         <Id>12345678</Id>         <Created>2023-07-12</Created>         <Customer>             <Id>                 <Org>Demo Org</Org>                 <Id>88343434</Id>             </Id>         </Customer>     </CInfo>     <PaymentStatus>         <OrgPaymentFileID>1234567</OrgPaymentFileID>         <PaymentStatusInfo>             <PaymentId>422049343</PaymentId>             <Status>Rejected</Status>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>011</Code>                 </ReasonCode>                 <!-- This is a comment -->                 <ReasonInfo>Creditor account info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>012</Code>                 </ReasonCode>                 <ReasonInfo>Creditor payment info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>         </PaymentStatusInfo>         <PaymentStatusInfo>             <PaymentId>24234234</PaymentId>             <Status>Rejected</Status>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>011</Code>                 </ReasonCode>                 <ReasonInfo>Creditor account info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>012</Code>                 </ReasonCode>                 <ReasonInfo>Creditor payment info invalid or missing</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>         </PaymentStatusInfo>         <PaymentStatusInfo>             <PaymentId>8453453</PaymentId>             <Status>Accepted</Status>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>001</Code>                 </ReasonCode>             </StatusInfo>         </PaymentStatusInfo>     </PaymentStatus> </Document>')
   
INSERT INTO MyXmlTable 
VALUES (2,
   ' <Document xmlns="urn:abc:Example"> <CInfo>         <Id>3852323</Id>         <Created>2023-07-12</Created>         <Customer>             <Id>                 <Org>Demo Org</Org>                 <Id>88343434</Id>             </Id>         </Customer>     </CInfo>     <PaymentStatus>         <OrgPaymentFileID>349232</OrgPaymentFileID>         <PaymentStatusInfo>             <PaymentId>193483</PaymentId>             <Status>Rejected</Status>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonInfo>123345345</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>034</Code>                     <!-- Invoice number is invalid or missing -->                 </ReasonCode>                 <ReasonInfo>Invoice number is mandatory</ReasonInfo>             </StatusInfo>         </PaymentStatusInfo>         <PaymentStatusInfo>             <PaymentId>4083421</PaymentId>             <Status>Accepted</Status>             <StatusInfo>                 <ReasonCode>                     <Code>001</Code>                 </ReasonCode>             </StatusInfo>         </PaymentStatusInfo>     </PaymentStatus> </Document> '
   )
```

Query:

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT
        -- xmldata
        tabl.col.query('.') AS xmlExtract,
        IIF(CHARINDEX('<!--', CONVERT(varchar(max), xmldata)) > 0,
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(max), xmldata), 
                      CHARINDEX('<!--', CONVERT(varchar(max), xmldata)) + 4,
                     (CHARINDEX('-->', CONVERT(varchar(max), xmldata)) - CHARINDEX('<!--', CONVERT(varchar(max), xmldata)) ) -4),
            NULL) AS Comment
    FROM
        (SELECT CAST(xmldata AS xml) AS xmldata FROM myxmltable) AS srctbl
         CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('//*:PaymentStatus/*:PaymentStatusInfo/*:StatusInfo') AS Tabl(col)
)
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(max),
            xmlextract.query('for $value in /*:StatusInfo/*:ReasonCode/*:Code
    return string($value)')),
    CONVERT(varchar(max),
            xmlextract.query('
    for $value in /*:StatusInfo/*:ReasonInfo
    return concat(string($value), ";")')
),
    Comment
FROM
    mytable
```

Comment: If you want the comments to be correlated then why aren't you extracting them as an outer apply over a query on the StatusInfo's xml?

Comment: Please edit your question, and (1) Please specify better rules for the Problem #1.  They are currently not clear, (2) Problem #2 is very easy to solve. (3) add ID to the desired output.

Comment: Looks like you are completely overcomplicating it. You can get comments in XQuery with `comment()`. And you just need to add a predicate in a `.nodes` call to check for `ReasonCode`. So something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/aL_LVY1l I note that the comment seems to come in different places, I've used `(.//comment())[1]` to just get the first comment in any descendant node.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not sure why this was closed, there seems to be a full repro here. This is not actually two problems, it's one issue which is that OP has not done the XQuery correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are completely overcomplicating it.

You can get comment nodes in XQuery using the `comment()` function.

And you just need to add a `[]` predicate in a `.nodes` call to check for `ReasonCode`, in order to filter out the `StatusInfo` nodes you don't want.

So something like this

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:abc:Example')
SELECT
  ReasonCode = StatusInfo.value('(ReasonCode/Code/text())[1]', 'char(3)'),
  ReasonInfo = StatusInfo.value('(ReasonInfo/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  Comment    = StatusInfo.value('(.//comment())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM MyXmlTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CAST(t.XmlData AS xml)
)) v(xmlVal)
CROSS APPLY v.xmlVal.nodes('
  Document/PaymentStatus/PaymentStatusInfo/StatusInfo [ReasonCode]
  ') x1(StatusInfo);
```

I note that the comment seems to come in different places, I've used `(.//comment())[1]` to just get the first comment in any descendant node.

Also, use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` rather than `*:` to search by namespace, as this is more performant.

You should also consider converting the actual column's data type to XML, rather than converting it every time you want to query it.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/aL_LVY1l)

Comment: I see that now. Your suggestion handled this perfectly! I were able to build on this and create a query that got me what I tried to do. Thank you so much for the help! :)

For anyone reading this needing to do the same: 
I didn't adjust on the retrieving of XML data. Onlyadjusted the value retrieved and changed out some text that made the value in ReasonInformation not unique but the Reason was essentially the same. It was juts a different ID/Number since it was a different file but the text was the same. That way I were able to use Distinct.

Comment: Quick question: What is the purpose of the "x1"?

CROSS APPLY v.xmlVal.nodes('
  Document/PaymentStatus/PaymentStatusInfo/StatusInfo [ReasonCode]
  ') x1(StatusInfo);

Comment: `.nodes` is a set-returning function, so you need to give it a table and columnn alias. `x1` is the table name, `StatusInfo` is the column name, but you can call them anything you like really. Why exactly you need `DISTINCT` is unclear, what is not unique about the data?

Comment: Ah. Yeah I see that now. Didn't think. Thanks. :)

We receive payment files from bank, and in them there is a code and details/description for the code. Sometimes there's also information in comments which gives more details to the description (silly I know, but we're not the one generating them, we just receive). I just need 1 result for a combination of code, description and comment, and not 100 of the same when looking through 10 000 files.